# Struct packing for multi processor data communication

Tags: c, embedded

On our ASIC we have two processors, which means two different compilers that behave slightly differently. We pass structs full of data between the two for communication, this happens quite often per second so we don't have much time to burn here.

The problem is that both compilers treat padding differently. So when we go to copy data from one domain to the other, we get values that don't align correctly. Our initial solution was to put **attribute**((**packed**)) on everything inside the struct. While this seems to work most of the time, it is by no means portable. As we are moving the code to different platforms, I'm noticing that not all compilers understand **attribute**((**packed**)) and I'd like to keep our code portable.

Has anyone here dealt with this kind of issue? What would you recommend?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't forget endianess either.  The idea of packing should be portable, but the *syntax* may be less so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally struct arrangement in C *isn't* portable, and so `__attribute__((packed))` or similar is generally the typical way to impose a fixed layout on a struct.

The other option is to manually add `pad` fields in appropriate places and be aware of each platforms' alignment constraints to ensure that across your two platforms the two structures match - but this is essentially manual `attribute((packed))`.

Note that the `pahole` utility from *dwarves* ([announcement](http://lwn.net/Articles/365844/), [paper](http://vger.kernel.org/~acme/pahole-ols2007.pdf)) is a great tool to check and view the alignment of structures, assuming your compiler emits ELF files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about pahole, I would have never found something like that on my own. I think maybe I'll write a script to parse the output from both of my elf files and verify that alignment is consistent.

Answer (score 3):

I would manually pack such structures, so that there is no padding issue with any compiler, present or future.

It *is* tedious, but it is a portable future-proof solution, worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why you shouldn't use structs for data protocols. It might seem like a harsh thing to say, but structs are unfortunately non-portable and therefore dangerous. You could consider doing something like this (pseudo code):

```
typedef struct
{
  uint32_t x;
  uint16_t y;
  ...
} my_struct_t;  // some custom struct

#define PROTOCOL_SIZE ( sizeof(uint32_t) + sizeof(uint16_t) + ... )


void pack (uint8_t raw_data[PROTOCOL_SIZE], 
           const my_struct_t* ms)
{
  uint16_t i=0;

  memcpy(&raw_data[i], ms->x, sizeof(ms->x));
  i += sizeof(ms->x);

  memcpy(&raw_data[i], ms->y, sizeof(ms->y));
  i += sizeof(ms->y);

  ...
}
```

And then make a similar unpack() function which copies raw data into the struct.

Advantages of this is: 100% portable. And if the protocol specifies a particular endianess, this function could also handle that conversion (which you would have to do anyhow.)

Disadvantages are one extra memory buffer and some extra data copying.